# How to implement QR code reader in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, qr-code

I want to show a QR code reader in my iPhone application inside main screen window.

How can I use the Zxing APIs in my app for creating the QR Reader? Can I use any other library for the same purpose?

Answer (score 5):

You can also try shop savvy iphone sdk for read qr code :
http://shopsavvy.mobi/sdk/

Thanks

Comment: Great link, but a licensing fee of 5000$ seems a bit steep. Am I missing something?

Comment: yea, $5K with ads, $40K without. Kinda of outrageous given that most of our apps are free.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to read QR code, Zbar is the best. Easy to integrate and good documentation is there. See their site http://zbar.sourceforge.net/. And see their tutorial http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html. I had successfully integrated Zbar in many of my projects.

Answer (score 3):

Try [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), its open source and i see an iphone part in source code